# Program not printing anything even till where it's supposed to

Tags: c, gcc

I was revisiting some basic loop programs in preparation for an academic test.

```
int N=10;
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
  {
    if (i==2) continue;
    printf("%d", i);
  }
int i=0;
while (i<N)
  {
    if (i==2) continue;
    printf("%d", i);
    i++;
  }
```

Both the loops are supposed to do the same thing, but the "while" version of it would fail since the continue causes the control to totally miss the increment ordered below itself.

But when I run the program, I just see the blinking cursor in the terminal window.

I expected at least the first loop to duly perform its duties and then the silent treatment from the terminal. But it seems to have a mind of its own. Does anyone have a good explanation?

Comment: Use printf("%d\n", i);

Comment: Your answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin

Comment: @VladfromMoscow That worked... But why?

Comment: @WilliamR.Ebenezer Because the buffer is flushed.

Comment: @fukanchik thank you!

Comment: You should move the increment up before the check for `i == 2`, or, even better, check for `i != 2` and skip the whole block.

Comment: @JL2210 Yes, but I want it that way. My doubt was why the first loop wasn't printing anything. The while loop would be kinda infinite, but the for should have printed something.